# porting windows 7 drivers to winXP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, driver, drivers

Is it possible to manually edit the driver to make it function on windows XP?

I guess there are many differences, but it must be possible for simple drivers, kind of porting the locations / buses they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean without re-compilation? If so its not recommended.

If you are willing to compile then use appropriate WDK and select appropriate build environment and try to build. You *may* have to change the code depending upon any APIs changed/availability.

Also note that drivers are compiled per OS i.e. there are different build environments for WinXP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7 etc.